# Running R scripts and showing plots in VSCode not working with radian and httpgd on macOS

Tags: r, vscode-extensions

I just moved from RStudio to R in VSCode with `radian` and `httpgd`, following the setup as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r. Everything has been successfully installed and I can basically run R code. However, the setup is not ideal and I have two, possibly related issues.

1. When opening VSCode and running an R script, I get the following error:

```
zsh: unknown file attribute: 1
```

As a result, I first need to go to the Terminal and switch to an R console by typing `radian`. But from what I see, it should be possibly to execute the R script with VSCode regonizing automatically that it is an R file.

2. Plots are shown in an external XQuartz window rather than in the Plot Viewer of VSCode using `httpgd`, although I followed the settings here (https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/973) to set up the `settings.json` as:

```
"r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.plot.useHttpgd": true,
    "r.rterm.mac": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/radian",
    "r.rpath.mac": "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    
        "radian": {
            "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/radian",
            "icon": "terminal-python"
        }
     ...
    }
```

Specs:

- Mac M1 Max with OS Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71).
- R version 4.3.2 Patched (2024-01-26 r85832)
- Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
- Python 3.11.7
- Visual Studio Code: 1.85.2 (Universal)

What could be the issue is that `which R` points to `/usr/local/bin/R`, but `R.home("bin")` points to `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin"`. Also, if I run `~ R` in VSCode, I get `zsh: permission denied: /Users/nb22i345`. Thus, I have the feeling that there are different installations of R and the paths are not set correctly everywhere, but not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I could finally resolve both issues, although not sure if the first solution is best.

1. I made `radian` the default terminal.
2. I followed the instructions here (https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Session-watcher), specifically adding the following lines to the `.Rprofile`:

```
if (interactive() && Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "") {
  source(file.path(Sys.getenv(if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") "USERPROFILE" else "HOME"), ".vscode-R", "init.R"))
}
```